# show a pdf in 64 bit in iexplorer

Tags: internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-apiexplorer

I need to show a PDF file with data, this data is data:application/pdf;base64, @Session["Pdf"] .

So the process works in my machine I open the PDF and automatically adn the PDF appears with a data in GOOGLE CHROME.

The problem is when I make this process in a web environment or IE , the HTML page does not show anything.

1 st tentative

`<body>
    <object data="data:application/pdf;base64, @Session["Pdf"]" type="application/pdf" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>It appears you don't have Adobe Reader or PDF support in this web browser. </p>
       <embed src="data:application/pdf;base64, @Session["Pdf"]" type="application/pdf" />
    </object>
</body>`

2 st tentative

`<div class="modal-body">
 <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64, @Session["Pdf"]" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
 @*<embed src="@Session["Pdf"]"></embed>*@
</div>`

3 st

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var data= "data:application/pdf;base64,@Session["Pdf"]" ;

if (data == "" || data == undefined) {
    alert("Falied to open PDF.");
} else { 
    //For IE using atob convert base64 encoded data to byte array
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        var byteCharacters = atob(data);
        var byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
            byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
        var blob = new Blob([byteArray], {
            type: 'application/pdf'
        });
        window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else { 
        // Directly use base 64 encoded data for rest browsers (not IE)
        var base64EncodedPDF = data;
        var dataURI = "data:application/pdf;base64," + base64EncodedPDF1;
        window.open(dataURI, '_blank');
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: This is  HTML generate       
`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML><HEAD>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV class="modal-body">  <IFRAME src="data:application/pdf;base64, 9/bbJc8lbT9fM/LsHHzafWpf3/n4yJr3++fv7X5YnET85sqZbe+NPnndL9gIPfP94zbKG3gsaFcOGxFhkEU3677zn7IWClqJNOIaBKwvqa3mZsrBrCjg" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"> &lt;/div&gt; </IFRAME></DIV></BODY></HTML>`

Comment: Hi, IE11 has ActiveX filtering. (Tools>ActiveX filtering) that blocks third party ActiveX controls like adobe flash.... Chrome has its own built-in pdf viewer. The File>Properties menu in IE will tell you which IE security zone the host maps to. By default only trusted and intranet hosts allow 32 bit Addons to run, Internet and Restricted hosts can only run x64... 32bit cpu's of coarse can't run 64bit ActiveX controls. Tools>Manage Addons>Show all addons... make sure your Adobe version is enabled and both x86 and x64 versions are installed on x64 machines.

Comment: When testing in chrome you can turn off the built-in Addon and turn on the Adobe plugin for chrome (if they still support it).

Comment: Sorry i follow all instructions and continue the same problem :(